# How to properly free char** in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have really been confused about this 2D char array

```
char **arg = malloc(sizeof(char*) * argc)
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  arg[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * size)
...
...
```

Now suppose after a series of operations, I forget the variable argc, how can I free those memory?
Can I do something like this? Is this absolutely correct under all circumstances?

```
char **tmp = arg;
while (*tmp != NULL){
    free(*tmp); 
    tmp++;
}
free(arg);
```

Comment: Arrays aren't NULL terminated, that's only valid for strings (char * in C)

Comment: you are in fact allocating memory for an array of char*, then allocating memory for each of items in the array. You have to free items first then free the array it self.

Comment: This is in fact not a bad idea, but you should explicitly put a `NULL` at the end of the array. I use this in many situations and it's good.

Comment: This is not a 2D array, but a pointer of pointer.

Comment: actually arg  it is a dynamic array of char*; that can hold (argc) elements; elements are dynamic array of char that can hold (size) chars; each array and elements are freed separately;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No

```
while(*tmp != NULL){
```

you may reach above a point where you will dereference memory which hasn't been assigned to and trigger undefined behaviour.

Or as suggested you can explicitly assign a `NULL` to the last allocated pointer, and in that case it will work.

Comment: @lplouis: keep track how many pointers you have allocated memory to

Comment: so argc must not be forgotten?

Comment: @lplouis Alternatively, allocate `argc + 1` pointers and manually set the last one to `NULL`.

Comment: And even though this can work if you add a `NULL` at the end, a much nicer way to do it would be `for (int i = 0 ; arg[i] != NULL ; ++i)` that way you don't need `tmp`

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the problems with freeing in a loop as shown is that an extra item (argc + 1) needs to be allocated and it has to be set to NULL.  An alternative technique is to first allocate the space for the pointers as you have done

```
char **arg = malloc(sizeof(char*) * argc)
```

Then, if you know all the subsequent items are the same size, allocate it in one huge block and set the rest of the elements at spaced offsets

```
arg[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * size * argc);
for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
   arg[i] = arg[i - 1] + size;
```

Freeing the space is a doddle: no need to even remember argc

```
free(arg[0]); /* this will free the memory used by all the elements */
free(arg);
```

The big disadvantages to this technique is that if any of the array elements overrun, it will corrupt the next item.  This cannot be detected so easily with a heap check unless it is the last item.

Answer (score -1):

if you define your char * array like this:

`char **arg = calloc( 1, sizeof( char * ) * argc );`

you can be sure that every undefined pointer will be equal to NULL

and then you can use the while loop almost like you suggested:

```
char *tmp = *arg;
while ( tmp != NULL ) {
    free( tmp ); 
    tmp++;
}
free(arg);
```